# XMl Schema: Unique key values within parent

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have the following XML:

```
    <enumTypes xmlns="tempURI">
    <enumType id="1">
        <enumValue id="1" value="Item1"/>
        <enumValue id="2" value="Item2"/>
        <enumValue id="3" value="Item3"/>
    </enumType>
    <enumType id="2">
        <enumValue id="1" value="Item1"/>
        <enumValue id="2" value="Item2"/>
    </enumType>
</enumTypes>
```

I also have the following schema:

```
                <xs:element name="enumTypes">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="enumType">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xs:element name="enumValue">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                            <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
    <xs:key name="enumTypeKey">
        <xs:selector xpath="enumTypes/enumType"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:key name="enumValueKey">
        <xs:selector xpath="enumTypes/enumType/enumValue"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xs:key>
```

I'm trying to force the enumValue ID's to be unique WITHIN a enumType, but so far I can only get it to force them to be unique across ALL enumTypes.

I'm guessing there's a problem with my selector XPath but I can't seem to get it sorted out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've only given a fragment of your xsd?   It's easier to debug if you can provide a working snippet.  I added a surrounding `<element name="root">` to make it validate.

The problem seems to be that the `enumValueKey` selector groups all of the `enumValues`, across of all the `enumType`'s; but you only want to group those within one `enumType`.

The only way I can see to fix it is to move the `<key>` for `enumValues` into the `enumType` element (and adjust the `xpath` selector), so the whole thing becomes:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="enumTypes">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:element name="enumType">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="enumValue">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:complexType>
                <xs:key name="enumValueKey">
                  <xs:selector xpath="enumValue"/>
                  <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
                </xs:key>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="enumTypeKey">
      <xs:selector xpath="enumTypes/enumType"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xs:key>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This works, in that it allows your XML example, and it forbids the following fragment (with two `1`'s) as it should:

```
...
<enumType id="2">
  <enumValue id="1" value="Item1"/>
  <enumValue id="1" value="Item2"/>
</enumType>
...
```

Let me know if this works for you.  I'm also interested if there is any other way to express this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your xs:key statements would be write inside the `<xs:element name="enumTypes">` element. So :

```
<xs:element name="enumTypes">
 ... what you want ...
 <xs:key ... and so on
</xs:element>
```